# Сложить значения в объектах с одинаковым ID

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть массив:

```
let users = [{id: 1, balance: 5}, {id:2, balance: 6}, {id: 1, balance: 1}]
```

Надо чтобы у объектов с одинаковыми id сложился `balance`, то есть получилось так:

```
let users = [{id: 1, balance: 6}, {id:2, balance: 6}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, например, такими двумя способами. Первый выглядит проще, но он менее эффективный (множественные прохождения по формируемому массиву). Второй использует промежуточную структуру, но меньше промежуточных операций.

```js
{
  const users = [{id: 1, balance: 5}, {id: 2, balance: 6}, {id: 1, balance: 1}];

  const users1 = users.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const id = entry.id;
    const same = acc.find( element => element.id === id);

    if (same !== undefined) same.balance += entry.balance;
    else acc.push(entry);

    return acc;
  }, []);

  console.log(users1);
}

{
  const users = [{id: 1, balance: 5}, {id: 2, balance: 6}, {id: 1, balance: 1}];

  const users2 = Object.entries(users.reduce((acc, entry) => {
    const id = entry.id;

    if (acc[id] !== undefined) acc[id] += entry.balance;
    else acc[id] = entry.balance;

    return acc;
  }, {})).map(([id, balance]) => ({ id: Number(id), balance }));

  console.log(users2);
}
```